# Magento function that sends data to browser

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to inspect and modify ALL output that is sent to the browser but rather than making hundreds of edits in the template files, I'd like to do this with one swoop by altering a function that send that data to screen.

Does this function exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this method:  `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::renderLayout` that renders the html.
If this does not fit your needs, there is this one that generates the output: `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::getOutput`